# Mail Cannot Save Information About Mailboxes

Tags: mail.app, email, disk-space

Sorry to come on with yet another stupid question, but when I start Mail.app, I'm seeing:

> Mail Cannot Save Information About Your Mailboxes Because There Isn’t
> Enough Space In Your Home Folder

I run a df ..

```
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused       ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk2s5   1.8Ti   11Gi  906Gi     2%  487554 19530667326    0%   /
devfs          207Ki  207Ki    0Bi   100%     718           0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk2s1   1.8Ti  935Gi  906Gi    51% 3295438 19527859442    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
/dev/disk2s4   1.8Ti  2.0Gi  906Gi     1%       2 19531154878    0%   /private/var/vm
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0           0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/home
/dev/disk2s3   1.8Ti  501Mi  906Gi     1%      42 19531154838    0%   /Volumes/Recovery
```

So I see /System/Volumes/Data/home and thought that maybe that was similar to the old Solaris thing of /export/home being the same as /home.  But there is nothing in that directory.

If I go to Apple --> About this Mac and look at storage, I see 1.06 TB free out of 2 TB.

This is stopping me from using my Mail client.  I tried the solutions [here](https://macreports.com/mail-cannot-save-information-about-your-mailboxes-because-there-isnt-enough-space-in-your-home-folder/).

None of them worked.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI though macOS is *based* on BSD Unix it has deviated quite a lot (because: Apple) and your home folder is essentially /Users/[USERNAME]/. And until Catalina the entire filesystem was on one big partition. In Catalina that has been split into system and user partitions. though I don't have a solution the home folder that error is likely referring to is the location with over a TB of free space.

Comment: No one?  :-(  Do I need to redo the fusion drive(s) and reinstall?

Comment: You don't mention what you have done already. This is possibly a disk error, so boot into recovery mode and run disk utility. If it finds an error it cant fix you can go with a 3rd party disk utility (careful not many support APFS) or backup, reformat and start over.